# Sequelize : Only returning one of many result for a nested include

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables:

1. Job post
2. recruitment phase
3. Interview slot

Their association is,
jobpost **has many** recruitment phases and 
recruitment phase **has many** interview slots

I am able to get all the recruitment phases of a job post by including the recruitmentphase association and group clause.

```
const jobPosts = await JobPost.unscoped().findAll({
            where,
            include: [
            {
                model: db.RecruitmentPhase,
                include: [{
                    model: db.InterviewSlot,
                },

            ],
            group: ['RecruitmentPhases.id'],
        });
```

But I am only getting one interview slot for the recruitment phase, event though there are **many** interviewslots for that recruitment phase.

I tried to do group clause inside include.

```
const jobPosts = await JobPost.unscoped().findAll({
                where,
                include: [
                {
                    model: db.RecruitmentPhase,
                    group: ['InterviewSlots.id'],
                    include: [{
                        model: db.InterviewSlot,
                    },

                ],
                group: ['RecruitmentPhases.id'],
            });
```

but it also giving only **one** interview slot

**EDIT**

jobpost model :

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const jobPost = sequelize.define('JobPost', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
            allowNull: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        jobTitle: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
            allowNull: true,
        },

    }, {
        timestamps: true,
        defaultScope: {
            attributes: { exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt'] },
        },
    });
    jobPost.associate = (models) => {
        jobPost.hasMany(models.RecruitmentPhase);
    };
    return jobPost;
};
```

Recruitment phase model :

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const recruitmentPhase = sequelize.define('RecruitmentPhase', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
            allowNull: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },

        phaseName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
            allowNull: true,
        },

    }, {
        timestamps: true,
    });
    recruitmentPhase.associate = (models) => {
        recruitmentPhase.belongsTo(models.JobPost);
        recruitmentPhase.hasMany(models.InterviewSlot);
    };
    return recruitmentPhase;
};
```

Interview slot model :

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const interviewSlot = sequelize.define('InterviewSlot', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
            allowNull: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        interviewDate: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: true,
        },
    });
    interviewSlot.associate = (models) => {
        interviewSlot.belongsTo(models.RecruitmentPhase);
    };
    return interviewSlot;
};
```

Comment: Post your models to further analyze them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I am not quite sure about, this is the correct answer and is the correct way to do it. 
But When I do the grouping for that  nested table 'interviewslot' with this  **'->'** ,  It worked.

```
group: ['RecruitmentPhases.id', 'RecruitmentPhases->InterviewSlots.id'],
```

Comment: Can you display the data you expect to see as the outcome of your query?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `group: ['RecruitmentPhases.id'],` in order to see the details of InterviewSlots.  As is, you're seeing a summary of interview slots...

Comment: if I remove ['RecruitmentPhases.id'] i wont be getting multiple recruitment phases.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you seem to be fetching `JobPost` instead of `RecruitmentPhase` if that is what you are looking to fetch from the database?

From what I understand - you are looking to fetch all the `RecruitmentPhases` with their job post accompanying the `InterviewSlots` allocated for each `RecruitmentPhase`.

Possible Code:
**(Updated)**

```
const rec = await db.RecruitmentPhase.findAll({
    include:[{model: db.JobPost, where:{ id:job_id }}, {model: db.InterviewSlot}]
});
res.json(rec)
//Expected JSON Data
{
  "RecruitmentPhase":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "phaseName":"Phase 1",
      "JobPosts": {
        "id":1,
        "jobTitle":"XYZ"
      },
      "InterviewSlots":[
        {//inteview slot #1 data},
        {//interview slot #2 data}
      ]
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "phaseName":"Phase 2",
      "JobPosts": {
        "id":1,
        "jobTitle":"XYZ"
      },
      "InterviewSlots":[
        {//inteview slot #1 data},
        {//interview slot #2 data}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: i have jobpost id. From where I need to get all the recruitmentphases for that jobpost. And for each recruitment phase, I need to get all of the recruitmentphases

Comment: A downvote? You just have to add a `where` clause to the query. Updated the answer.